# Visual Studio Community 2019 - Running, Installation and Reporting Issues

Tags: installation, visual-studio-2019

I have been trying to run Visual Studio 2019 since the last windows update but it will only open the splash screen and then quit itself. After resetting, uninstalling, reinstalling, and rebooting multiple times. I also uninstalled and deleted the installation files but I am honestly out of ideas now.

I can't even report it to the VS community because when I attempt to do so from the installer I just receive this error upon attempting to authenticate with no manner to reset the account:

> Error signing in: '{"code":-32000,"message":"Failed to start host 'desktopClr.x86$IdentityHost' (ErrorKind: Error HResult: 8013153B)","data":{"stack":" at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.d__50.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.d__66.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.LocationService.d__35.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.HubController.d__9.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n at Microsoft.ServiceHub.Controller.HubController.d__8.MoveNext()","code":"-2146233088"}}

I assume this has something to do with the accounts, but I couldn't find any proper way to reset them or to actually report this.

Other things I have tried:

- From the Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt: Running devenv with /safemode and /ResetSettings didn't do anything,

Has anyone faced these issues?

Thanks.

Comment: Hey Perry! I haven't had a chance to try it out! I am going to give this a try between today and tomorrow. Hadly had any time to sit down lately. Thank you for the reply! Let me check this out. I am going to follow your steps.Some of the things I already tried so let me try all of this and give a full post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Visual Studio Community 2019 - Running, Installation and Reporting
>   Issues

**First**, I suggest you could delete all files about the account records under `C:\Users\{username}\AppData\Local\.IdentityService` folder and then restart VS Installer to test again.

**Second**, we suggest you could download [vs_collect.exe tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=12493) to get the whole log about the error and then share with us to troubleshoot your issue more quickly. The log exists under `%TEMP%vslogs.cab`. You can refer to [this link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/visual-studio-and-net-log-collection-utility/) for more info.

You can try these further suggestions:

**Suggestion**

**1)** run `devenv /resetuserdata` and `devenv /ResetSettings` under Visual Studio Developer Command Prompt to reset the VS Environment to the default.

**2)** If all these do not help, please try to reinstall it completely.

Uninstall VS and when you finish it, please delete any folder like this:

`C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0_xxx`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019`

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer`

**Besides**, if you only have VS2019 Community on your agent, you can execute `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe`.

And **note** that it will uninstall every VS2017 and VS2019 completely on your agent. And then reinstall VS2019.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Hello Perry, and thanks for the reply.

I just got some time to try out your steps and unfortunately, it is not working for me still. 

1. I ran the commands in the developer command prompt like last time and on the 'ResetSettings' the program tried to open and closed again.

2. Uninstalled and attempted a fresh install. Once again deleted those folders but the program quits after the splash screen

3. Installed the collectTool. While I do not see a vslogs.cab. Only a vslogs.zip in the folder.

Also, the installer still displays the same error when attempting to report an issue.

Comment: Sure. That is the actual one. You can share with us to troubleshoot your issue. If you try any steps without success. You could use `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\resources\app\layout\InstallCleanup.exe` to reinstall VS thoroughly(all VS2017 and VS2019 versions).

Comment: Well okay so, been away a couple of days because apparently my Windows image was corrupted and I had to re-install the entire OS. Could be my SSD. Now it's working but that's not really 'a solution'. Thank you! 

Fixed it, but really was accidentally had to take the nuclear option.